# Angular delete request not working

Tags: angular, http-delete

if you could please help me with this, I don't know why isn't working..

I'm working with angular 4 using asp.net mvc as my backend, **using postman, my delete request works,** but in angular, I can't figure out why isn't, and there are no errors...

I'm building small angular crud app and trying to get User Id from the same row in the table which I've populated...

**I don't have any errors in my console or my compiler,** but nothing seems to happened when i click a button which triggers my delete function from my component...
here's the code

```
 export class user{
 Id: string;
 Name: string;
 }
```

In my service, I have a functioning get and post method, but delete is not working, code:

```
    deleteUser(id: string) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:48622/user/' + id, options)
        .map(res => res.json());

    }
```

in my component.ts

```
   userlist: user[];

   DeleteUser(id: string) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?') == true) {
        this._usermanagementservice.deleteUser(id)
            .subscribe(x => {
          //this populates table with names, function is working, not sure should I call it this way so my table can be updated?
                this.LoadAllUsers();
            })
      }
    }
```

and in my app.component.html, in what I think is the main problem..

Noted that I want to show only names of users with button for delete in the same row...

```
      <table style="width:100%" class="table table-striped" 
      id="billing_history_table">
      <thead class="head">
        <tr>
            <th>User Name</th>

            <th></th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let u of userlist">
            <td>{{u.Name}}</td>
             <td><a (click)="DeleteUser(e.id)"><span class="glyphicon 
         glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the confirm alert?

Comment: no, same thing :/

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo change `DeleteUser(e.id)` to `DeleteUser(u.Id)`

this is how it would look like

```
 <table style="width:100%" class="table table-striped" 
  id="billing_history_table">
  <thead class="head">
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>

        <th></th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of userlist">
        <td>{{user.Name}}</td>
         <td><a (click)="DeleteUser(user.Id)"><span class="glyphicon 
     glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

try and give proper names to variables, it makes debugging easy

Answer (score 0):

Should your code not read

```
DeleteUser(u.Id)
```

Note: u.Id and not e.id

Can you confirm the right ID is being passed to your API

Comment: yeah, fixed the typo, still, no errors, chrome debuger shows error like id in my component.ts in undefined, for example, id that's been stored in my databaes goes something like this AKSO5-SLF55-LSLO2

Comment: also debugger shows I'm missing params, params are undefined, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, in my database, column was name userId not id, so when I changed in my html DeleteUser(u.id) to DeleteUser(u.userId) it worked!